# Finding max flow from minimum s-t cut

Tags: algorithm

It is easy to get a s-t cut with minimum capacity given a max flow f by using
a BFS from the source on the residual graph. Is there an algorithm to get a max flow f, given a minimum capacity s-t cut?

Answer (score 0):

No, basically. The problem is that a min cut in general tells you very little. Given a network, form a new network by attaching a new arc from the sink to a new vertex that becomes the new sink, with capacity equal to the old max flow. Now the min cut is just that arc -- no information about the rest of the network.